# How to return a dictionary from a list where the keys are items in the list and the values are the number of occurrences in that list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Create dictionary from a list, where items of list become the keys and values become the number of times they are in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
 d = {}

 for items in your_list:
     d[items] = your_list.count(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

A Counter turns a sequence of values into a defaultdict(int)-like object, mapping keys to counts.

```py
from collections import Counter
c = Counter([0, 1, 2, 0])   # c is (basically) { 0 : 2, 1 : 1, 2 : 1 }
```

A useful method of Counter is `most_common`.

```
# print the 10 most common words and their counts in the Counter Dict on myList:
for word, count in Counter(myList).most_common(10):
    print(word, count)
```